# Problem running a scripts in Python shell using PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x

```
Have have the following code in PyCharm:

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    #
    # Define __str__() method in our class can control how it gets printed.
    #
    def __str__(self):
        return "({0},{1})".format(self.x, self.y)
```

I need to do in PyCharm to run the code in Python shell
And enter the following in Python shell

```
>>> p1 = Point(2,3)
>>> p2 = Point(-1,2)
>>> p1 + p2
```

What do I need to do in PyCharm to run and enter things in Python Shell?

Comment: The problem will be with the + operator. You have overloaded the __str__ operator, but that it never used in this example. You could use str(p1) + str(p2) or overload the operator + (with __add__)

Answer (score 0):

If you run the python shell you have an empty environment without your defined codes.

You can use [Python debugger (PDB)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pdb.html?highlight=pdb#module-pdb) to dig into your code:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  # if that is the point you want to inspect
    #
    # Define __str__() method in our class can control how it gets printed.
    #
    def __str__(self):
        return "({0},{1})".format(self.x, self.y)
```

The code wil run until 'import pdb; pdb.set_trace()' and stop with a prompt where you can do anything like in the default python shell.

Additional tipps:

1. Don't use single-char-variables because in pdb some variables are mapped to pdb-functions
2. Inside press c to continue the code run (key bindings pdb)
3. If you use python3.7 or newer you can use '[breakpoint()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=breakpoint#breakpoint)' instead of 'import pdb; pdb.set_trace()'